# Stuck while installing Manjaro using USB drive

Tags: arch-linux, grub, manjaro

I have used `dd` to put the image on a USB drive and then booted into it using the BIOS. After I start the boot option, in the GRUB menu I am presented with a singular white underscore on a black background.

If I use CTRL + ALT + F2 I arrive at a command line.

What can I do from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was using the free drivers which I will switch to non-free after installation

Answer (score 0):

Re-download the image. 
Verify its checksum matches.
Reformat the flash drive.
Rewrite it with dd

or

Use a [faster tool](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media)